# Site features such as Logout/Chat/Help are difficult to find due to icon help/hover text ("A list of all ... Stack Exchange sites")

Tags: feature-request, design, top-bar, logout

The help/hover text says *"A list of all 181 Stack Exchange sites"*, and yes, there are several sites and sets of sites here:

- Current community
- Meta site for the current community
- Top communities in which you participate
- A list of all communities (with a search/filter)

But it also includes several important features for the *current* site/community:

- Site/community help (also found in the footer at the bottom of the page, but much more conveniently accessed here)
- Site/community chatrooms, which to my knowledge isn't available anywhere else
- Log out, which to my knowledge also isn't available anywhere else

Based on the hover text, it's very difficult to find the the "log out" functionality (as well as chat).  I know it's not intentional -- Just an unintended side-effect.  I was curious after reading a site-meta "how do I log out" question (without an answer yet, and without a link to the duplicate).  I had to look it up myself (since I've never had the *need* to log out myself).

I hovered over the far-right icon several times while searching for "log out", but never clicked that icon because I never thought "log out" would be under "a list of all ...".  I assumed that it would be a hyperlink to [stackexchange.com/sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).

Some possible alternative hover texts:

- *Site Tools*
- *Community Tools*

Either of these (or potentially something else) would be a very simple change that IMHO would improve discoverability of the features under that icon.  I can't be the only one who skipped clicking/expanding that toolbar icon based on the hover/help text, right?

---

*Hover text:*

[image: Stack Iconbar]

---

*Actual results:*

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't tag this as a bug, but a feature-request maybe.

Comment: Most of your complaint about it being misleading is quite literally describing a list of all sites - just one that happens to be separated into different sections but is nonetheless still a list of all sites. You seem to be more bothered by the fact that the log out button is hidden within that list, but that gets a bit lost under all the talking about how a list is not a list.

Comment: @animuson Fair enough.  Again, my expectation based on the hover text was that it would simply link to a "list of all sites" (like [stackexchange.com/sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday)).  But you are correct - The "sections" can each be considered a subset of a the "list of all sites", with the union of those sections being "the list of all sites).  And yes, my main point is that there are other important community features that aren't easily discoverable given the current hover text.  So I rewrote the question to focus on the main problem - Thanks for pointing it out.